# Como evito que aparezca el null cuando la persona no tenga segundo nombre?

Tags: javascript, json, null

Este codigo crea una tabla en html, llamando una variable desde un archivo js, el cual contiene un archivo json (contiene datos como id, primer nombre, segundo, apellido, partido, votos, etc etc... provenientes de un AJAX request). Mi problema es que no se como hacer para que cuando la persona no tenga segundo nombre no me aparezca NULL, sino solo espacio vacio, este es el codigo:

```
function crearTabla(){
  var tablaSenado = document.getElementById('senate-data');
  datos = agregarTablaEnHtml(data.results[0].members);
  tablaSenado.innerHTML = datos;
}

function agregarTablaEnHtml(membersArray){
    var html = '<thead><tr><th>URL links</th><th>First Name</th><th>Middle Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Party</th><th>State</th><th>Seniority</th><th>Percentage of votes with party</th></tr></thead>';
    html += '<tbody>';

    membersArray.forEach(function (members) {
        html += '<tr>';

        if (members.middle_name == null) {
            html += '<td><a href="' + members.url + '">' + members.first_name + ' ' + members.last_name + '</td>';
        } else {
            html += '<td><a href="' + members.url + '">' + members.first_name + ' ' + members.middle_name + ' ' + members.last_name + '</a></td>';
        }

        html += '<td>' + members.first_name + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + members.middle_name;
        html += '<td>' + members.last_name + '</td>';
        html += '<td class="party">' + members.party + '</td>';
        html += '<td class="state">' + members.state + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + members.seniority + '</td>';
        html += '<td> % ' + members.votes_with_party_pct + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    });
    html += '</tbody>';
    return html;
}

crearTabla (data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla sería utilizar el operador `or (||)`. Con `(members.last_name||" ")` se realiza la comparación, si `members.last_name` es `undefined` entonces se pone un espacio en blanco.

```js
let membersData = [{
    url:"url 1",
    first_name: "first_name 1",
    last_name: "last_name 1",
    middle_name: "middle_name 1"
  },{
    url:"url 2",
    first_name: "first_name 2",
    middle_name: "middle_name 2"
  },{
    last_name: "last_name 1",
    middle_name: "middle_name 3"
  }];

function crearTabla(){
  var tablaSenado = document.getElementById('senate-data');
  datos = agregarTablaEnHtml(membersData);
  tablaSenado.innerHTML = datos;
}

function agregarTablaEnHtml(membersArray){
    var html = '<table><thead><tr><th>URL links</th><th>First Name</th><th>Middle Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>';
    html += '<tbody>';

    membersArray.forEach(function (members) {
        html += '<tr>';     
        html += '<td><a href="' + (members.url||" ") + '">' + (members.first_name||" ") + (members.middle_name||" ") + (members.last_name||" ") + '</td>';       

        html += '<td>' + (members.first_name||" ") + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + (members.middle_name||" ");
        html += '<td>' + (members.last_name||" ") + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    });
    html += '</tbody></table>';
    return html;
}



crearTabla();
```

```html
<div id="senate-data"></div>
```